# How can I have trust in a Community AMI offered on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I want to launch a Fedora 24 instance on Amazon EC2. The [Fedora Cloud download page](https://getfedora.org/en/atomic/download/) no longer offers links to Fedora 24 AMIs, instead it offers links to "Fedora 25 Atomic Host" images (these are new stuff, things are changing too fast nowadays).

On the Amazon EC2 Service Page, I can search for Fedora AMIs in the "Community AMIs" subset. This delivers a number of AMIs marked as "Fedora"

[image: Fedora AMIs on Amazon]

Why should I trust these images? How I can I find out whether they are the real deal?

Comment: You can't, really. Get them from someone you *do* trust. Fedora's not really a great option, IMO, for this very reason - it's intended to be rapidly moving and targets the desktop. EC2's primarily for servers, where Fedora's short lifecycle is a pretty decent drawback.

Comment: Why the wild downvotes?

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't see this. The desktop/server distinction is a malady that has been imported from the "differentiated pricing" world of MS. EC2 is perfectly cool for testing out systems on short lifecycles. Indeed, it's practically made for that. Ok, I could go with Red Hat but that would be USD 50/month on a t2.micro.

Comment: @ceejayoz Not to mention that for certain workloads, such as web sites, the recent software and short lifecycle is exactly what you need.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Perhaps, but in that scenario you'll need either a plan to update when the official AMIs go away after a few months, or a trusted third-party provider. I took a look at the Fedora page's cached version and they appear to have purged the old v24 AMIs, not just removed links to them.

Comment: [Centos Public Images](https://wiki.centos.org/Cloud/AWS#head-78d1e3a4e6ba5c5a3847750d88266916ffe69648) are probably a better approach. Centos (Community **Enterprise** Operating System) aims for RedHat compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look on [getfedora.org/atomic](https://getfedora.org/en/atomic/download/), which has links to the current images which are actually created by the Fedora Project.

[image]

Comment: There is now also https://alt.fedoraproject.org/cloud/ which "cloud base images" I see.

Comment: Yes, that has the non-Atomic AMIs.